# Display name of node in a tree control on clicking it(MFC/VC++)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I want to display the name of any node in a tree view struture when clicked on it.Is there any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Winapi:
Use [TreeView_GetSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a [TreeView_GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macros.

```
                        TVITEM tvitem = {0};
                HTREEITEM hSelected = NULL;

                WCHAR wText[MAX_PATH] = {0};

                hSelected = TreeView_GetSelection(g_hTree);

                if (hSelected)
                {
                    tvitem.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
                    tvitem.pszText = wText;
                    tvitem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
                    tvitem.hItem = hSelected;

                    TreeView_GetItem(g_hTree, &tvitem);
                }
```

Now *wText* holds name of clicked item.